# UIButton image saturation changes

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

In storyboard I have button with image (not background image):

[image]

But when I lunch app, image saturation changes =(

[image]

Hot can I resolve this issue? I want to save image brightness and saturation (like in storyboard).. Please any answers.. Thanks

Comment: Is the image anywhere near to a UINavigationBar with transparency turned on? If so - that translucency could be the culprit.

Comment: Are you sure your image's color mode is not CMYK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible explanations:

1. Be sure your image is in RGB mode and not CMYK.  iOS devices do not handle CMYK images correctly. (In photoshop look in the "Image" -> "Adjustments" -> "Mode" menu.
2. (This is the most likely explanation) This is a result of the limited color range of different screens.  Different monitors and screens have different depths of color they are capable of displaying.  So in your case your computer's monitor has a wider range of greens that it can display than the iPad (or vice versa).  We have encountered this most with greens and oranges.  You'll just have to experiment to see what color will get you the closest to where you want to be.

Here is a very good explanation of this phenomenon:

http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/color-spaces.htm